# Could not find method wrapper() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper}

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have added the wrapper in `build.gradle`:

```
tasks wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.2.0'
    distributionUrl = 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip'
}
```

and get an error:

```
Could not find method wrapper() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper}, build_9k7l9u7llhnu4m9p95ig4uxzk$_run_closure1$_closure3@1fde438] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
```